# CSS not loading after site URL changes

Tags: html, css, jsp, web

So, basically we changed our site URL from a big one to a rather small URL.
for example, www.example.com/portal/public/media/12345 to www.newsite.com/12345

After these changes I see that the css is not loading anymore, is there anything that I need to add/remove to my jsp files?

I am accessing the css in my JSP files like: 
`<link href="/resources/portal.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

resources folder is under ther web/webroot folder.

Error Log:
WARN 31 Jan 2018 13:43:08,694 () [PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/portal/public/media/portal/resources/portal.css;jsessionid=799088F1EB2D765BAF6B5AB0F62364FC.tcserver0] in DispatcherServlet with name 'portal'

In the chrome browser console I get the following error: GET newsite.com/portal/resources/… net::ERR_AB

Please help.

Comment: You have not posted enough info for anyone to help you here. Maybe try posting the relevant style tags and directory structure. Its likely that your styles are loaded relative to the current page and changing the url makes it improperly resolve.

Comment: sorry @Deadron ; I added the link tag.

Comment: Just enter www.newsite.com/resources/portal.css in your browser. If it doesn't load then there is something wrong with the location or server configuration regarding the css file. The http status code might give you a hint (like redirect, access errors etc).

Comment: @nharrer Entring www.newsite.com/resources/portal.css in the browser doesnt load the css, it does go to the java controller mapped to /media

I get this in the server console logs:
WARN  31 Jan 2018 13:43:08,694 () [PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/portal/public/media/portal/resources/portal.css;jsessionid=799088F1EB2D765BAF6B5AB0F62364FC.tcserver0] in DispatcherServlet with name 'portal'

And in the chrome console I get the following error:
GET http://www.newsite.com/portal/resources/portal.css;jsessionid=799088F1EB2D765BAF6B5AB0F62364FC.tcserver0 net::ERR_AB

Comment: Have you checked the generated html (show source in the browser). See what the <link rel="stylesheet"..> tag looks like.

Comment: this is how it looks like '<link href="/portal/resources/portal.css;jsessionid=486A141EB0DB8711C1DD96843AFDC0A6.tcserver0" rel="stylesheet">'

Answer (score 0):

We ended up changing the mapping of the new site to www.example.com/portal instead of www.example.com/portal/public/media
That solved the issue.